# it is not necessary to place value 2> value 1

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, kotlin-coroutines, control-flow

Problem: Propose a structure that repeats 5 times and within it load 3 integer values. Accumulate only the largest of each list of three values.

I have a question, because in this exercise it is not necessary to place value 2> value 1 on the second line.

```
fun main(parametro: Array<String>) {
var suma = 0
for(i in 1..5) {
    print("Ingrese primer valor:")
    val valor1 = readLine()!!.toInt()
    print("Ingrese segundo valor:")
    val valor2 = readLine()!!.toInt()
    print("Ingrese tercer valor:")
    val valor3 = readLine()!!.toInt()
    suma += when {
        valor1 > valor2 && valor1 > valor3 -> valor1
        valor2 > valor3 -> valor2
        else -> valor3
    }
}
println("El valor acumulado de los mayores de cada lista de 3 valores es : $suma")
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
valor1 > valor2 && valor1 > valor3 -> valor1
```

- This is true, if and only if valor1 is the highest value.
- If valor1 is equal to or less than either valor2 or valor3 (or both), then it is false

```
valor2 > valor3 -> valor2
```

- If Line 1 is false, then valor1 must be <= valor2 or valor3 (or both).
- Then, if valor2 > valor3, it is also >= valor1 (because that was checked in Line 1)
- If valor2 == valor3, then either of them must be >= valor1, otherwise Line1 would have been true.

What's left is that valor1 could be == valor3, in which case it doesn't matter if you "return" valor1 or valor3. Line1 would be false, Line2 true only if valor2 is > than both valor1 and 3.

To make it more clear:

```
Valor1 Valor2 Valor3 Line1  Line2 Result
  1      2      3    False  False Valor3 = 3
  1      3      2    False  True  Valor2 = 3
  3      2      1    True   -     Valor1 = 3 
  1      1      2    False  False Valor3 = 2
  1      2      1    False  True  Valor2 = 2
  2      1      1    True   -     Valor1 = 2
  2      1      2    False  False Valor3 = 2
  2      2      1    False  True  Valor2 = 2
  1      1      1    False  False Valor3 = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot possibly get past the first condition of the `when` statement if `valor1` is greatest, so there is no logical reason to check again if it might be greater than `valor2`.

You can more simply compare these, and any number of items with

```
suma += intArrayOf(valor1, valor2, valor3).max()
```